# Regex deprecation warning confusion

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I've went through a number of other entries here on SO regarding this particular issue, but I haven't been able to apply any responses from those to my particular issue. I'm getting "Flags not at the start of the expression" warning for these regexps:

```
white_space = r'(?ms)(\s*(\{[^\n]*?\})?\s*)' # regexp for normal whitespace/comments
import_re = re.compile(r'^\s*import\s+"(?P<filename>.+?)"(\s+as\s(?P<asname>[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_.]*))?%s$' % white_space)

# Returns the function name, parameter list, and result variable (or None) as a tuple
param = white_space + r'([$%@!?~]?[\w\.]+|#[\w\.]+#)' + white_space
params = r'%s(,%s)*' % (param, param)
m = re.compile(r'^\s*macro\s+(?P<name>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(\.[a-zA-Z_0-9.]+)*)\s*(?P<params>\(%s\))?' % params)

macro_call_re = re.compile(r'^\s*([\w_.]+)\s*(\(.*\))?%s$' % white_space)
```

I don't see any inline modifiers here, so I'm confused. Is it because of the % thing at the end?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the value of `white_space` and `params`?

Comment: If `params` is supposed to be treated as literal text, you should use `re.escape(params)`

Comment: You'll get better help if your question include an [mcve] -- ideally, code that we can copy and paste locally to reproduce the problem you're asking about. There are a number of unresolved variables in your current example that mean we can't just run it.

Comment: I have added the unresolved variables, hope this helps! Unfortunately I cannot really resolve self.lines[0].command because it is very much context-specific (these are regexps from a custom compiler), but you can take it as any normal string, say "foo".

So, my understanding here is that the % symbol here is used to just insert extra text inside the raw regexp string. But why would this be classified as inline modifier and trip up that deprecation warning?

Comment: Ah! I think I see it - it's because `white_space` starts with `(?ms)` that this happens, because this raw string is then concatenated into other regexps... OK but then what would be the best way to update these expressions into something that won't get a deprecation warning? :)

Comment: OK actually managed to figure it out. I have separated this into two regexps, one is `white_space_core` that is just the regexp without `(?ms)`, and then there's `whitespace = r'(?ms)%s' % white_space_core`. Then I update other regexps I listed to use `white_space_core` and add `(?ms)` at the beginning of those. Phew!